# How to move files to list template gallery in SharePoint Hosted app

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-hosted-app, list-template, move

I Have created **SharePoint Hosted app**.

With the app deployment I am uploading document files (.stp file) in adocument library. Now I want to move these files to my host webs **list template gallery**. In short I want to move a file from **app web to host web**.

Is there any possibility to do this?

Comment: Could you share the code you have?

Comment: i have tried using SP.RequestExecutor but it is not working

Comment: Do you have any working solution?